# How to handle OAuth 2.0 authentication screen for WPF applications?

Tags: .net, wpf, oauth

dealing OAuth 2.0 with web based app is farily simple since the system redirects to the service authentication website and returns to your website with the a token for accessing content.

but what to do for windows desktop applications, more specifically wpf?

How is the user going to authenticate? I can't user webrequest in the code(obviously) because he/she has to approve?

What do we do?

Comment: Have you tried to use webbrowser control?